# Switching between different sources in GStreamer 0.10 not working

Tags: python, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I am trying to switch between two streams using `input-selector` but I am getting the error:

```
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_property'`
```

This is my Python code:

```
def __init__(self):
      pipeline_string=(
                       'videotestsrc pattern=0  ! in. '
                       'videotestsrc pattern=2  ! in. '
                       'input-selector name=in  ! autovideosink '                           
                       )
      self.pipeline=Gst.parse_launch(pipeline_string)

  def cam1(self):
      switch = self.pipeline.get_by_name('in')
      stop_time = switch.emit('block')
      newpad = switch.get_static_pad('sink0')
      start_time = newpad.get_property('running-time')    
      switch.emit('switch', newpad, stop_time, start_time)
```

I think those two functions are only thing you need. I wrote it so that I can test the `input-stream` element. The thing that happens is that I get `None` type when I try to get the `sink0` pad. Why ?

Comment: `get_static_pad('sink0')` works fine for me here on my Laptop, at least it returns a `GstPad object` instead of `None`. Maybe check your gstreamer installation or related configurations?

Comment: Sorry but with my Python-binding it is version `0.10.36` which is invoked. Sorry for being not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Okey after a couple of hours trying to solve this I found out (thanks to guy named Tim) that iam using sink0 instead sink_0 .